# How to check if map.find() result is end C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map

```
std::map<long long, string> directory;
```

I am trying to find a specific number, if that number is found in the map assign it to a variable. But it seems the if condition is not working, its entering the if even when the number is not found which is causing error. Whats missing ?

```
        auto it = directory.find(12345);
        string response = "value not found"
        if (it != directory.end());
        {
           response = it ->second;
        }
```

Comment: This question fails to meet the "complete" requirement of a [mcve]. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The semi-colon that should be at the end of the second line (after `found"`) has fallen down to the next line (after `if (...)`). So your code doesn't compile, but if it did then the if clause does nothing.

Comment: Such a silly mistake, thanks you for pointing out.Its working now !

Comment: Compilers warn for this. Turn on/up the warnings. Aside: This can be written as `if (auto it = directory.find(12345); it != directory.end()) {...}` in C++17.